# Form not validating js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I want to validate the form but it is returning true value even it is false

I want return false if name.length > 10 and show error text but it is directing to the action page how?. Can anybody help me with this
Code:

```js
function ShowError(id, error) {
  element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.getElementsByClassName('return-error')[0].innerHTML = error;
}

function ValidateForm() {
  var return_value = true;

  var name = document.forms['MyForm']["name"].value;
  var phonenumber = document.forms['MyForm']["number"].value;
  var email = document.forms['MyForm']["email"].value;
  var password = document.forms['MyForm']["pass"].value;
  var cpassword = document.forms['MyForm']["cpass"].value;
  if (name.length > 10) {
    ShowError("name", "*Username is too long");
    return_value = false;
  }
  return return_value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>login & Continue</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="context.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white fs-1" href="index.html">
        <img src="assets\logo.png" alt="Bootstrap" width="60" height="54" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" /> The IN-Planet
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="login d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center m-5">
    <div class="card bg-dark flex-wrap" style="width: 30rem">
      <img src="assets\Travelling-to-India1.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fillter" />

      <form name="MyForm" action="home.html" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="get">
        <div class="m-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Username" name="name" id="name" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="number" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Phone Number" name="number" id="number" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="password" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="password" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="cpass" id="cpass" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg ms-3" value="SignUp" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="bg-dark text-light text-center p-5">
    <div class="container">
      <p>© 2023 THE IN-PLANET. All rights reserved.</p>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
        <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.facebook.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\fb.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.instagram.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\insta.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.whatsapp.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\whae.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="service.html">Our Services</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me with this.It is returning true value even it is false. Help me with this!!!!!!!!

Comment: It looked like there was an error just before it submitted; you might throw a try/catch block around everything in the function and return false in the catch block so you can see the error without the form submitting.

Comment: You are passing "name" as the id to `ShowError()`, but there is no element with "name" as the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, which I am highlighting here.

1. No PreventDefault() function to see the validation
   *if you don't add prevent default, your browser will reload the page when you submit the form.*
2. Wrong calling to DOM element

```
  element = document.getElementById(id);
  document.getElementsByClassName("return-error")[0].innerHTML = error;
```

This code is not making sense, because you're assigning an ID to an element and reusing it to call classes. You can achieve it by this code

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("return-error")[0].innerHTML = error;
```

It will call all the elements with the `return-error` class and will use the specific index you assigned.

**Correct Version of Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>login & Continue</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link href="context.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white fs-1" href="index.html">
          <img
            src="assets\logo.png"
            alt="Bootstrap"
            width="60"
            height="54"
            class="d-inline-block align-text-top"
          />
          The IN-Planet
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="login d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center m-5">
      <div class="card bg-dark flex-wrap" style="width: 30rem">
        <img
          src="assets\Travelling-to-India1.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="card-img-top img-fillter"
        />

        <form
          name="MyForm"
          action="home.html"
          onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); ValidateForm()"
          method="get"
        >
          <div class="m-5">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control m-3"
              placeholder="Username"
              name="name"
              id="name"
            />
            <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
            <input
              type="number"
              class="form-control m-3"
              placeholder="Phone Number"
              name="number"
              id="number"
            />
            <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
            <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control m-3"
              placeholder="Email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
            />
            <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control m-3"
              placeholder="Password"
              name="pass"
              id="pass"
            />
            <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control m-3"
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              name="cpass"
              id="cpass"
            />
            <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
            <input
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn-info btn-lg ms-3"
              value="SignUp"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="bg-dark text-light text-center p-5">
      <div class="container">
        <p>© 2023 THE IN-PLANET. All rights reserved.</p>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
          <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.facebook.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\fb.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.instagram.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\insta.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.whatsapp.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\whae.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
            <a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
            <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
            <a href="service.html">Our Services</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS Code

```js
function ShowError(id, error) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("return-error")[0].innerHTML = error;
}

function ValidateForm() {
  var return_value = true;

  var name = document.forms["MyForm"]["name"].value;
  var phonenumber = document.forms["MyForm"]["number"].value;
  var email = document.forms["MyForm"]["email"].value;
  var password = document.forms["MyForm"]["pass"].value;
  var cpassword = document.forms["MyForm"]["cpass"].value;
  if (name.length > 10) {
    ShowError("name", "*Username is too long");
    return_value = false;
  }
  return return_value;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>login & Continue</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="context.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white fs-1" href="index.html">
        <img src="assets\logo.png" alt="Bootstrap" width="60" height="54" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" /> The IN-Planet
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="login d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center m-5">
    <div class="card bg-dark flex-wrap" style="width: 30rem">
      <img src="assets\Travelling-to-India1.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fillter" />

      <form name="MyForm" action="home.html" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); ValidateForm()" method="get">
        <div class="m-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Username" name="name" id="name" />
          <div style="color:red" class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="number" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Phone Number" name="number" id="number" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="password" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="password" class="form-control m-3" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="cpass" id="cpass" />
          <div class="return-error m-3"></div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg ms-3" value="SignUp" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="bg-dark text-light text-center p-5">
    <div class="container">
      <p>© 2023 THE IN-PLANET. All rights reserved.</p>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
        <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.facebook.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\fb.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.instagram.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\insta.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">
            <a href="www.whatsapp.com"
              ><img src="assets\socialmedia\whae.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content col-md-4">
          <a href="service.html">Our Services</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```